# How to fire a method when UISlider stops?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I've got a `UISlider` that allows the user to changes values. I want a `UILabel` to continuously update as the slider moves from left to right.

So, I wrote my `UISlider` method like this:

```
    - (IBAction)yearsSlider:(UISlider *)sender
{
    self.yearsLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", sender.value];

}
```

This works just fine.  I need to fire a different method when the user stops the slider.

I thought about using `NSTimer` for this - so rewrote the above method like so:

```
     - (IBAction)yearsSlider:(UISlider *)sender
    {
        self.yearsLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", sender.value];

 if (!self.timer){
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(requestCalculation) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];] 
    }

    }
```

Then in the `requestCalculation` method I invalidate the timer and set it to nil = like so:

```
 [self.timer invalidate];
self.timer = nil;
```

This slows it down - but the method is called while the slider is moving. Which is not what I want.

I am aware that I can use `self.mySlider.continuous = NO;` which means the target method is only fired once when the user lifts their finger off the slider. The problem with this is my `UILabels` are not updated as the user sliders their left and right on the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. But you are canceling the timer in the wrong method. You want to cancel the (previous) timer in the `yearsSlider:` method, not the `requestCalculation` method.

```
- (IBAction)yearsSlider:(UISlider *)sender {
    // Cancel the current timer
    [self.timer invalidate];

    self.yearsLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", sender.value];

    // Start a new timer in case this is the last slider value
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(requestCalculation) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

BTW - two seconds seems to be a rather long delay for this check. Something smaller would probably be better.

Do not invalidate the timer in `requestCalculation`. Just set it to nil.

FYI - Use `NSNumberFormatter` to convert the slider value to a user displayed value. Doing this will ensure the value is formatted properly for the user's locale.

Comment: Using a timer seems a very ugly hack for this.

Comment: @user3477950 I agree but this answer explains what the OP was doing wrong with their attempt. Your answer (and the other) is probably the better solution.

Comment: As stated in comments - this works perfectly. However it seems I can do it better. I will mark this as answered as it solved the problem asked with the code provided and thank you for the NSNumber tip!

Comment: @downvoter - why? This answer solves the OP's problem. It may not be the best solution but that doesn't make the answer wrong.

Comment: Maddy's answer addresses the OP's question, so I don't think you should down-vote it. user3477950's solution of using a separate action tied to touch up inside is, I think, a better way of doing it, but Maddy did help the user fix his code, and answered the question that was asked. (voted)

Answer (score 3):

set `self.mySlider.continuous = YES;`, and update your label in the method corresponding to `UIControlEventValueChanged`.

Then, add a method with a **different** selector for the events `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` and perform the (apparently expensive) computation in there.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this please?

Comment: @Tander What example? I've told you all the necessary information. You need to use the `addTarget:selector:forControlEvents:` method of `UIControl`.

Comment: Thanks figured it out. It does solve the problem in a clean way. So I'll up vote. rmaddy's answer solves the question asked based on the code provided. Thanks again

Comment: I agree with user3477950. (voted) Since sliders are UIControl objects, they will automatically trigger an action on a touch up inside event **AS WELL AS** on a value changed event. This is cleaner than using a timer. BTW, I would suggest wiring your "value has stopped changing" IBAction method to both touch up inside and touch up outside. Otherwise, if the user drags his/her finger off-screen while dragging the slider, you won't get notified.

Comment: @DuncanC You're right, I've added that control event as well, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the UIControlEvent `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` to fire an action when the user lifts the finger (maybe you need to check touch cancelled and touch up outside too)

```
[self.mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(_ended) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```